# Error :The OutputPath property is not set for project

Tags: uwp, package, desktop-bridge, appx, packager

I am working on a UWP app that is integrated with Windows Application Packaging Project and desktop bridge application.

My application includes the following Projects:

1) UWP project

2) UWP project without any solution file that acts as a library to the main UWP project and works as a reference to it

3) Class library project

4) Desktop application

5) Windows Application Packaging Project : Set as a StartUp project; the main UWP project is set as a entry point and Desktop application another reference

The possibilities I tried:

1. Changed the configuration of all project to x86
2. Changed the UWP projects to x64 (throws an error: Mismatch between processor architecture)
3. Changed the allowed projects to change to CPU (throws an error: Mismatch between processor architecture)
4. Edited the project solution file to update the architecture field when passed blank to x86
5. Set the Output path of the Class library project (all other projects had a path set)

Before integrating desktop bridge application I was able to create the appxUpload file using Create Package Wizard and successfully uploaded the bundle on the Microsoft Store.
The problem started When I integrated the desktop bridge application in my existing UWP app when building and creating a bundle file in Release x86 configuration.
Whenever I try to create a bundle file it does not throw any error in the Error list but I found that the error appears in the Output window that points to UWP app.

Error :`The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. Configuration='Release' Platform='AnyCPU'.`

Following are the screenshot of the Project Properties:
[image: Main Uwp Porject properties]

[image: UWP library project]

[image: Class library properties]

[image: Desktop Application properties]

[image: Packager Properties]

[image: Solution Explorer]

[image: Error]

Comment: Hi Shakita, any update for this issue?

Comment: Actually, I was trying to create a appxUpload file of my project that had x86, x64, arm and arm64 configurations. So the arm64 was causing this issue. After some research I have found that UWP does not support arm64. Therefore, when we create a bundle we should uncheck arm64 in Create package bundle wizard. Thank you

Comment: Glad to know you've located the issue, and you can consider adding it as answer to help others which may encounter similar issue:)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for this problem. Below is the work around.

I was trying to create a appxUpload file of my project that had x86, x64, arm and arm64 configurations. So the arm64 was causing this issue. After some research I have found that UWP does not support arm64. Therefore, when we create a bundle we should uncheck arm64 in Create package bundle wizard. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

UWP Projects do not support AnyCPU, you need to make sure your configuration manager is set up correctly:
[image: Configuration Manager]

Take note of the Active solution configuration/platform and go through each combination to make sure the correct platform is chosen.

Comment: Thanks, I changed all project configurations to x86 but now I am getting following
Error:There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\UWP\bin\x86\Release\UWP.exe", "x86".  Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're building the whole solution instead of building separate project, right?

If so, you should pay attention to this switch box for your solution:

[image]

Actually the error `The OutputPath property is not set for project(project name)... Configuration='Release' Platform='AnyCPU'.` showed much info for us.

It indicates that specific project is built in `Release and Any CPU`, then what you need to do is open that specific project's properties and check its output path for `Release and Any CPU` combination. It indicates the output path is **empty** for this page.

**Note:** One thing we have to know is the content of project's properties page is different between different combinations. For example: If i have a project which has `Debug and Release configuration`, `X64, X86 and Any CPU Platform`. In this situation we have `2*3=6` kinds of combination. And we have different settings for these six combinations.

[image]

**To resolve this error you can try:**

Not familiar with UWP, but if you get the `OutputPath not set for Project A... Combination='xx' and Platform='xxx'`, right-click `Project A` in `solution explorer`=>properties, change the configuration to 'xx', platform to 'xxx', and enter the value of the OutPutPath can resolve this error.

For more details you can have a look at my **Update** in [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648100/build-wildcard-fueled-group-of-projects-from-sln-en-masse-to-their-respective-o/56659975?noredirect=1#comment100064901_56659975).

Also, for the third pic you showed above, the Outputpath is empty, please correct it since it may cause error when you build the solution with Release and X86`enter code here` combination.

Sorry for the delay and hope it helps:)